# How can I get the BIOS from my motherboard?

Tags: backup, bios, flashing

I am interested in making a backup of the BIOS I obtained from a programmer at FoxConn a few years ago. Apparently, there was a huge problem with the motherboards being able to accept more than 6GB of RAM, and after a lot of persistence I was able to get them to fix the BIOS. However, they never uploaded it to their website, instead the programmer emailed me a link to DropBox.

Now I am a little bit concerned, because the link is now broken, and I have no way to get the BIOS. I am wondering if it is possible to obtain the BIOS from my motherboard by "reverse flashing" it onto something I can make into a backup.

The motherboard is a FoxConn Renaissance from 2008, which still works wonderfully since the upgrade. The BIOS version that only I have, as far as I am aware is 853F1S03, and I can't find it anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: Whatever tool you used to flash the BIOS may well have a "backup" mode that can be used to copy or backup your current BIOS. A current version of the tool, if available on their website, might be able to do the job.